# Destructuring array of arrays to get access to individual elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, destructuring

So, I am working with an array of arrays like this:

```
const arrOfArrs = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
```

For my example problem, I can only access the  individual elements by using a nested loop,
I'd like to be able to (if possible) use a single loop, using destructuring to access the individual elements of each sub-array

Example (I know this works somewhat but not as intended): I need access to each element. And it needs to be flexible. In case I'm working with different sized arrays. (3 x 3 or 4 x 4 etc.) Writing the el1, el2, el3 wouldn't be flexible for other sized array of arrays

```
 arrOfArrs.forEach(([el1, el2, el3]) => console.log(el1));
```

Above would console log each first el of each sub array: example el1 would log: 1, 4 , 7. I'd like to get individual element 1, then 2, 3, 4 etc. And be able to loop through it all. Is this possible?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Unless the indicies you need to target are hard-coded, destructuring won't work (at least not without some ugly convoluted code). Iterate over the array instead of trying to put each element into separate identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map over your parent arrays and spread each of them into a new container array, like so:

```js
const arrOfArrs = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

const destructuredArray = [] 

arrOfArrs.map(array => destructuredArray.push(...array))

console.log(destructuredArray)
```

Is this the kind of thing you're aiming for?

Comment: It is not performant to  iterate over the `arrayOfArrs` with `Array#map()`, then calling `Spread syntax` for all of the nested arrays and pushing the result to `destructuredArray` variable when you can just use `Array#flat()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use just [Array#flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Code:

```js
const arrOfArrs = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

const destructuredArray = arrOfArrs.flat()

console.log(destructuredArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

To truly access each item in a **single loop**, you first want to *flatten* the array as done here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865042/6127393
In the snippet below I am directly iterating the flattened array result without storing it in a new variable (basically a 'one-liner').

```js
const arrOfArrs = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
[].concat.apply([], arrOfArrs).forEach(one => {
  console.log(one)
});
```